# Data structure for storing and sorting different objects/types? Storing various different sensor data, sorted by time

Tags: python, c++, data-structures

I am trying to come up with a solution for holding different types of sensor data sorted and in order by time.
So for example I will have:

- GNSS/GPS data at times 100, 101, 102, etc.
- IMU data at times 100, 100.01, 100.02, .... 101, 101.01, etc.
- Lidar data at times 100, 100.1, 100.2, ... 101.1, 101.2, etc

I need to process the data in order of time. They are different types/objects.
Right now I am doing something crude like:

```
# The actual data structures stored would look something like below 
# (with some fields not explicity written out for clarity, the point though is each 
# data structure is different).
# 
# struct GnssData {
#    double time; double latitude; double longitude; };
# struct ImuData {
#    double time; double acc_x; double acc_y; }; 
# struct LidarData {
#    double time; double ranges[100]; double angles[100]; };

# We can assume each individual list/array/vector is sorted by time. 
# The actual implementation right now is std::vector<LidarData> all_lidar_data; std::vector<GnssData> all_gnss_data; std::vector<ImuData> all_imu_data;
all_lidar_data = [100, 100.1, 100.2, 100.3, 100.4, 100.5]
all_gnss_data = [100, 101, 102, 103]
all_imu_data = [100, 100.01, 100.02, 100.03]

if all_lidar_data[0].time < all_gnss_data[0].time and all_lidar_data[0].time < all_imu_data[0].time:
  # process lidar data
  # pop all_lidar_data[0]
elif all_gnss_data[0].time < all_lidar_data[0].time and all_gnss_data[0].time < all_imu_data[0.time:
  # process gnss data
  # pop all_gnss_data[0]
```

This kind of works but it gets really messy when there is no gnss data for example, so the list/array is empty. Thus also need to check if there is gnss data first before doing the time comparison.

Ideally what I would like to do is have some array that contains all the sensor data in order of time, so its as simple as

```
while len(all_sensor_data) > 0:
  # process all_sensor_data[0]
  # remove all_sensor_data[0]
```

Where all_sensor_data, using the example above, would be: GNSS(100), IMU(100), Lidar(100), IMU(100.01), ... IMU(100.09), Lidar(100.1), IMU(100.1), ..., GNSS(101), IMU(101), Lidar(101),

Is there any suggestions on a design pattern, or data structure that may solve this issue? Im technically programming in c++ but wrote the examples in python for clarity.
Edit: This is a real time application so data is continuously added when its available.

Comment: Wrap the sensor data in a common class, use `std::set` with a custom sort.

Comment: @sweenish do you mean have something like a base class SensorData with a member element time? Or do you mean have one big SensorData object that has members for GNSS, IMU, and Lidar data, then store in a set?

Comment: @user2840470 I think you should clarify those cascading `if` statements concerning the time to sort by.  Say you have 3 values representing time and you want to sort something like, `(a1, b1, c1)` and `(a2, b2, c2)`.  So you compare times a1 < a2, and if those are equal, b1 < b2, and if those are equal, finally c1 < c2?  That's where I'm confused with your description of sorting by time.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added some more code/examples to hopefully clarify. Does this explain it any better?